# JavaScript IF with AND/OR.. not working

Tags: javascript

Can someone who is a master at JS tell me what's wrong with this?

```
if ( $.trim($("#add-box-text").val()).length < 2 && $.trim($("#add-box-text").val()) != "Click here to add an item" ) {
    // If it's LT than 1 Character, don't submit
    $("#add-box-text").effect('highlight', {color: '#BDC1C7'}, 500);

    // Refocus
    $("#add-box-text").focus();
}
```

Comment: Well for one thing: You are checking to see if a string is less than 2 characters long. Then you are making sure it is not "Click here to ...." but.... "Click here to..." is MORE than 2 characters... so it would fail the first check. Why bother with the second?

Comment: So maybe it should be it can't be under 2 characters or EQUAL to the string. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, if it's less than 2 characters, it's never going to equal that string.

EDIT: Modified to reflect your comments.  You want to check that it's >= and not equal to that string.

```
var trimmed = $.trim($("#add-box-text").val());
if ( trimmed.length >= 2 && trimmed != "Click here to add an item" ) {
    $("#add-box-text").effect('highlight', {color: '#BDC1C7'}, 500);

    // Refocus
    $("#add-box-text").focus();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's it... I don't want avalue that's under 2 characters.. I also don't want the default value: "Click here to add an item"

which is why it had the AND above ideas?

Comment: @nobosh - See my comment. It is redundant. If you dont want a value under two characters, you need to do `> 2` and not `< 2`